# Using Windows task Scheduler to execute a commnd within an exe file

Tags: task, exe, scheduler

I have an program i use to import data using UTF-8 .dat files to my server.
Usually, i run the exe, then select my config file (xml) which will direct the exe to the right folder containing the .dat files and also the parimiters for said files. And then i have to click on button to "run" the import.

Using Windows Task Scheduler, i set up to run the exe, and add arguements for the config file.
Scheduled to run every 5 minutes. All seems great, it runs and completes.

Yet nothing is being uploaded. is there another command that i should add to actually execute the import?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Brendan

Answer (score 0):

It depends on command line parameters your exe supports. It looks like you miss some option on your exe's command line.

First, try to run your exe from command line (cmd.exe) so that it makes all job done, than use that command in Task Scheduler.

Command-line help is usually printed on `yourapp.exe /?` command. Be sure to run it from command line shell (cmd.exe), not from Start -> Run menu.